# WPF and Thread Marshalling

Tags: wpf, multithreading, windows-phone-7

Apologies if I I just did not figure out the actual approach but I have looked through various blog posts and don't feel any closer to the answer.

I am writing a WP7 application that is essentially a stop watch with a conversion of time to cost.

The Model contains methods Start() and Pause() and a double property Cost. In the ViewModel I am using ICommands for Start() and Pause(), which trigger the underlying model functions. However after a call to Start(), I want the UI to reflect the increasing cost.

I have considered several approaches:

1. ViewModel subscribes to Model via a self implemented subscriber
   model and the Model notifies all subscribers every few milliseconds shilst the model is   running.
2. View Model StartCommand starts a background worker that fires a RaisePropertyChanged event on the Cost Property every few milliseconds.

I have opted for the second proposal as the Model does not at all require threading (It merely logs the times when the user presses start and pause and uses this in the cost calculation). I based the approach on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(VS.95).aspx

However I get an "UnauthorizedAccessException" when I try to run this. The code is below:

The Backgroundworker gets created as VM member in the Constructor

```
public MeetingCostViewModel()
{
    _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker
    {
        WorkerSupportsCancellation = true,
        WorkerReportsProgress = false,
    };
    _backgroundWorker.DoWork += DoWork;
}
```

The StartCommand triggers the Background worker to run

```
private DelegateCommand _startCommand;
    public ICommand StartCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _startCommand ?? (_startCommand = new DelegateCommand(
                delegate
                {
                    _meetingCost.Start();
                    _keepUpdating = true;
                    if (_backgroundWorker.IsBusy != true)
                    {
                        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
                    }
                }));
        }
    }
```

And this is the actual worker method which is based on http://blog.lab49.com/archives/1166

```
private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler temp = PropertyChanged;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Cost"));
        }
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

I am unsure if this is the right approach but I want to keep the View databound and  without 'code behind', yet most alternative responses here require explicit setting of the control which I want to avoid at any sensible cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the UnauthorizedAccessException means that you are accessing a UI object from a different thread. Your event handler fires on the wrong thread.

Change the code to use a DispatcherTimer which will fire on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for reiterating that concept. searching for  "MVVM DispatcherTimer" brought the following solution that works perfectly well to light.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/0f239d78-a08f-437f-8b80-8df24cb6d168

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to do your updates in the report progress event handler of `BackgroundWorker`. It will automatically marshall to the correct thread.